# Getting object from three fiber components

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am kinda new to react and three fiber so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Say I have a mesh like so:

```
<mesh position={functionToGetPos()}>
  <sphereGeometry args={[1, 32, 32]}/>
  <meshStandardMaterial color="hotpink"/>
</mesh>
```

and I have a function in the component where I want that mesh to be referenced in:

```
const myFunc = () => {
  let pos = new THREE.Vector3();
  pos = pos.setFromMatrixPosition(object.matrixWorld);
  ...
}
```

where I want the mesh to be the object.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) like this:

```
const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>(null);

return (
   <mesh ref={meshRef}/>
);
```

after which you can use the ref using `meshRef.current`.